# Compare error message in golang

Tags: go, error-handling

Let's say I create a new error in golang like so

```
err := errors.New("SOME_COMMON_ERROR_CODE")
```

In java, I'm used to being able to get Exception with `GetMessage()` messages. How would I compare that error if returned?

```
if some_err := some_package.DoSomething(); some_err != nil {
    if some_err.GetMessage() == "SOME_COMMON_ERROR_CODE" {
        // handle it however.
    }
}
```

How is this done in golang?

Comment: according to to the [source](https://golang.org/src/errors/errors.go) , `Error()` method returns the message, so you can do `some_err.Error()` to get the message.

Comment: https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declare a package level variable with the error:

```
var errExample = errors.New("this is an example")
```

Use this value when returning errors. Compare against this value to check for the specific error:

```
if err == errExample {
    // handle it
}
```

Export the variable if code outside the package needs to access the error:

```
var ErrExample = errors.New("this is an example")
```

Use it like this:

```
if err == somepackage.ErrExample {
    // handle it
}
```

[Here are some examples](https://godoc.org/net/http#ErrBodyNotAllowed).

Avoid comparing against the string returned from the error's [Error()](https://godoc.org/builtin#error.Error) method. It can make your code brittle.

Comment: Is it possible to make the `var erros.New` a `const`?

Comment: This won't work if the underlying error is a different type, even if it has the same output from `err.Error()`.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/uujqxa3Qdq

Comment: @Kaedys Errors values are not equal just because they have the same string representation.  The function `errors.New()` is explicitly designed to return a unique value that will not compare == to any other error value. For example the expression `errors.New("x") == errors.New("x")` evaluates to false.  The playground example is working as designed.  It may be OK to compare string representations in Java, but it's not the practice in Go.

Comment: Yes, that was my point, Cerise.  Defining your own package constant that has an `Error()` output equal to what you're checking for won't always work, because comparing errors does NOT compare just the `Error()` output.  You have to either do a string comparison (brittle) or the package the error came from needs to define exported error constants you can compare to.

Comment: ...I literally just said that.

Comment: Sorry, my "just" in that case wasn't meant to indicate that they were compared, but that such a check wouldn't be sufficient even if they were compared.  My point is, if you're getting an error back _from another package_, the _only_ ways to check that error for a particular value are to check the `Error()` output (which is brittle), or to compare it against an exported error defined by the originating package.  If the package didn't export any error values, defining your own with the same message for comparison _won't work_.

Answer (score 10):

we can also compare errors like that:

1. If you creating error like this [Error Code Based]

_

```
var errExample = errors.New("ERROR_CODE")
```

then you can directly check error like this

```
if err.Error() == "ERROR_CODE" {
//Do something error caught
}
```

2. If you creating error like this [Error Code Based]

package mypackage

```
var NoMoreData = errors.New("No more data")
```

Now you can check anywhere like this

```
if err != mypackage.NoMoreData{
//Do something error caught
}
```

If you want to compare two errors at a time then you can do like this:

```
err1 := errors.New("Error Caught")
err2 := errors.New("Error Caught")

fmt.Println(err1 == err2) // false | Never do like this

fmt.Println(err1.Error() == err2.Error()) // true | Do like this
```

That's All.