# Global defined error does not equal in RPC return

Tags: go, rpc

I have a couple of error type variables defined globally. For example,

```
var ErrFileNotExist = errors.New("File does not exist")
```

On server side, this is used as a return value in an RPC, for example,

```
func (t *Type) F(args *T1, reply *T2) error {
   ...
   // some code here.
   return ErrFileNotExist
}
```

But on client side invoking this RPC and getting the return value, compare it with the global `ErrFileNotExist`, it does not match. That is,

```
...
// client set up
e := c.Call(...)
log.Prinln(e) // File does not exist
log.Println(e == ErrFileNotExist)  // false
```

Why this happens? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Is the error declared in a separate package?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560241/compare-error-message-in-golang#41560303