# How to design an individualized error, and then test for it (as opposed to the description in the error)?

Tags: go, error-handling

<sup>Context: I am an amateur dev coming from Python and I am just starting with Go</sup>

**(Python background to show how I manage errors today)**

In Python, the typical way to raise exceptions (errors) with your own "error type" is

```
class noMoreBeer(Exception):
    pass

try:
    a_function()
except noMoreBeer as e:
    print("there is no more beer ({e}), go buy some")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"unexpected exception happened, namely {e}")
else:
    print("thinks went fine")
```

The main part I would like to port to Go philosophy is that I created my own exception which can have optional explanation text, but I check for `noMoreBeer`, **not the error text**.

**Now back to Go**, I read several pages on how to handle errors (while I was annoyed first, I now find that it makes for better code), among them on the [Go Blog](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go). Out of this I tried to replicate the above, but the code below does not work (JetBrain's Goland points to `return Error.noMoreBeer()` and `if err == Error.noMoreBeer()`)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Error interface {
    error
    noMoreBeer() bool
}

func thisFails() Error {
    // returns my specific error, but could also percolate some other errors up
    return Error.noMoreBeer()
}

func main() {
    err := thisFails()
    if err != nil {
        if err == Error.noMoreBeer() {
            fmt.Println("go buy some beer")
        } else {
            panic("something unexpected happened")
        }
    }
}
```

**Is there a way in Go to create such specific errors?**

One of the main drivers for them in my case is that I do not rely on the *text* passed in the error, but on a [class|whatever] which, if it has a typo, will be an error.

Comment: `return Error.noMoreBeer()` -- Here you're calling a method on a type, not a value, that doesn't make much, if any, sense in Go. You almost never want to invoke methods directly on a *type*. What exactly is `thisFails` supposed to return? What were you hoping the expression `Error.noMoreBeer()` would produce?

Comment: Read [Working with Errors](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors) and the older [Error Handling](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) on the Go Language blog.  There's also a [section in Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#errors) on this topic.

Comment: @mkopriva `thisFails` was supposed to return my specific error (to be checked for in `main()`). `Error.noMoreBeer` was what I wanted to check against.

Comment: @CeriseLimón: thank you for the links. It seems that what I want to achieve is simply `var noMoreBeer = errors.New("no more beer")`, and I can test directly against `noMoreBeer` (and not the description, what I was trying to avoid). I will continue reading and will post an answer once I have a satisfactory solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Does [Compare error message in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560241/compare-error-message-in-golang) answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

There's four functions you should look into. Here's [the official Go blog post](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors) for this subject. It was introduced in Go 1.13.

- [`fmt.Errorf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf): Create a new error with some details. Can wrap errors with `%w`.
- [`errors.New`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#New): Create a new error type that can be wrapped and compared with functions introduced in Go 1.13.
- [`errors.Is`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is): Compare an error variable with an error type. It can unwrap errors.
- [`errors.As`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#As): Compare an error variable with an error interface implementation. It can unwrap errors.

Answer (score 1):

My first shot at a solution:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var noMoreBeer = errors.New("no more beer")

func thisFails() error {
    // returns my specific error, but could also percolate some other errors up
    return noMoreBeer
}

func main() {
    err := thisFails()
    if err != nil {
        if err == noMoreBeer {
            fmt.Println("go buy some beer")
        } else {
            panic("something unexpected happened")
        }
    }
}
```

The key point I understood reading https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors is that I can test against a variable which type is `error`. This is functionally equivalent to the Python example I started with.

Comment: This is the correct approach if you're checking for specific error *values*. From your question however, I surmised you wanted to wanted to check against a "class" of errors... probably because I don't know enough python.

Comment: I also thought the goal was to compare types, not values.  See [Compare error message in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41560241/5728991) for previous question on comparing values.

Comment: @CeriseLimón. I marked this question as duplicate, updated your other answer - thanks!

Comment: @mkopriva: yes, you are correct. This is the way to create "individualized" errors in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a type switch.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// the interface
type NoMoreBeerError interface {
    noMoreBeer() bool
}

// two different implementations of the above interface
type noMoreBeerFoo struct { /* ... */ }
type noMoreBeerBar struct { /* ... */ }

func (noMoreBeerFoo) noMoreBeer() bool { return true }
func (noMoreBeerBar) noMoreBeer() bool { return false }

// have the types also implement the standard error interface
func (noMoreBeerFoo) Error() string { return " the foo's error message " }
func (noMoreBeerBar) Error() string { return " the bar's error message " }

func thisFails() error {
    if true {
        return noMoreBeerFoo{}
    } else if false {
        return noMoreBeerFoo{}
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("some other error")
}

func main() {
    switch err := thisFails().(type) {
    case nil: // all good

    case NoMoreBeerError: // my custom error type
        if err.noMoreBeer() { // you can invoke the method in this case block
            // ...
        }

        // if you need to you can inspect farther for the concrete types
        switch err.(type) {
        case noMoreBeerFoo:
            // ...
        case noMoreBeerBar:
            // ...
        }

    default:
        // handle other error type
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have been using errors by cutome implementation of error interface in production without any issues. This is helping detect the error and find root cause more efficiently.

```
package errors

type Error struct {
    err      error // the wrapped error
    errType  ErrorType
    errInfo  ErrorInfo
    op       Op

    // domain specific data
    userID    int
    requestID string
}

type (
    ErrorType string
    ErrorInfo string
    Op        string
)

var NoMoreBeer ErrorType = "NoMoreBeerError"

func (e Error) Error() string {
    return string(e.errInfo)
}

func Encode(op Op, args ...interface{}) error {
    e := Error{}

    for _, arg := range args {
        switch arg := arg.(type) {
        case error:
            e.err = arg
        case ErrorInfo:
            e.errInfo = arg
        case ErrorType:
            e.errType = arg
        case Op:
            e.op = arg
        case int:
            e.userID = arg
        case string:
            e.requestID = arg
        }
    }

    return e
}

func (e Error) GetErrorType() ErrorType {
    return e.errType
}
```

By this, you can use errors as you'd use them but adding the capabilities of a expansion as needed.

```
e := errors.Encode(
    "pkg.beerservice.GetBeer", 
    errors.NoMoreBeer, 
    errors.ErrorInfo("No more beer available"),
).(errors.Error)

switch e.GetErrorType() {
case errors.NoMoreBeer:
    fmt.Println("no more beer error")
    fmt.Println(e.Error()) // this will return "No more beer available"
}
```

Working example on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/o9QnDOzTwpc